# SBT execute task of other project before running run task

Tags: scala, sbt, build-tools

I have two projects in my SBT buildfile `core` and  `runner`

```
lazy val core = (project in file("."))
lazy val runner = (project in file("runner"))
   .settings(mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("Main"))
```

I would like `packageBin` task of `core` project to be executed before I execute `run` task of my `runner` project. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I am able to call the packageBin on project1 when project 2 is run

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
    organization := "com.abhi",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.4"
)

lazy val project1 = (project in file("project1")).settings(
    name := "project1",
).settings(commonSettings)

lazy val project2 = (project in file("project2")).settings(
  name := "project2",
  (run in Compile) := ((run in Compile) dependsOn(packageBin in (project1, Compile))).evaluated
).settings(commonSettings)
```

Now if you do

```
set "project project2" run
```

you will see that it calls packageBin on project1 first

BTW, I am not an SBT expert and the syntax of SBT changes daily. So I am not sure if the above code is the best and most recent way of doing what you want.